# running python from the terminal windows

Tags: python, pandas, terminal, command-prompt

I am testing to run a python file from the command prompt. Running a simple code like `print('Hello world')` is working. But if I run below code I get an error.

code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('Test.xlsx')

df.to_csv('_TEST.csv', ';')
```

Error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Test.xlsx'
```

The file is in the right directory. Because the code works on the IDE, Visual studio code.

I hope someone knows it

Comment: Are you sure it is in the same directory? It can be inside another folder in the directory or one directory upper

Comment: What is the command line you use to run your snippet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to import .xlsx into Python: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543061/unable-to-import-xlsx-into-python-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: find the file you want to use in file explorer, hold `shift` and `right-click` the file, there should be an option called `copy path` click that. Now in your terminal create a variable- `file=` and paste the output on the right side of the variable. then pass that into pandas `pd.read_excel(file)`

Comment: thanks @Umar.H!! I also need to write the path for `to.csv(file)`

Comment: that's simple `from pathlib import Path` ; `trg_path = Path(file).parent.joinpath('new_file.csv')` then do `df.to_csv(trg_path,index=False)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two case that Python does not recognize your files:
Let's say your scripts named `hello.py`

**Case 1:** you're running `python hello.py` and the files is somewhere else, say at `another_folder/Test.xlsx` then:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('another_folder/Test.xlsx')

df.to_csv('_TEST.csv', ';')
```

**Case 2:** you're running `python another_folder/hello.py` and the files is also at the same folder, say `another_folder/Test.xlsx` then it is also:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('another_folder/Test.xlsx')

df.to_csv('_TEST.csv', ';')
```

The reason is that you have to write the path of your files relative to of `current working directory`, **not** relative to the python file.
**Hint:** run `pwd` in command line to see what directory you're at.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is in the right directory, it may be a problem with the directory in which you are executing the script. Change your directory in the command prompt to the same directory shown in the terminal in Visual Studio Code.